# pure Pipes not detective argument-change when the argument is an object

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'pagerPipe'
})
export class PagerPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], pager: Pager): any {
    var start = (pager.activePage-1)*pager.pageSize;
    var end = pager.activePage*pager.pageSize;
    console.log(start,end);
    return array.slice(start,end);
  }

};
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
export class Pager {
  pageSize:number;
  activePage:number;
};
```

It works just fine when I set the arguments to have individual pageSize and activePage,
But when I pass a class that has both pageSize and pageNumber, the pipe doesnt detect argument changes

Unfortunately Im using angular-cli via ng build and "plunker" wont let me upload vendor.bundle.js saying "save failed"

http://www.mediafire.com/file/2ndirjwkhgq06gq/Test.zip
unzip and run index.html

By the way, Id like to avoid using Impure pipes.

Comment: Have you tried triggering change detection manually?

Comment: @echonax not yet, how do I do that? Btw arent pipes suppose to trigger everytime an input/argument changes?

Comment: If you don't change the object reference, I think it would be hard for Angular to tell that there's a change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually

Comment: Try and create an immutable pager and see if it helps.

Comment: @Avi how do I do that? Also, is it possible for my pager class to detect changes on its properties?

Comment: you can create a function that accepts pager object and return new pager object (the function will create new pager with the new props) and return the new instance. call it whenever one of the props changes, instead of set value to the prop set new object. If I am not clear I will add a post with some code....